# Checkboxes in jQuery Mobile Scroll View

Tags: checkbox, jquery-mobile, scroll, jquery-mobile-dialog

Is there any reason why checkboxes in the hidden portion of a scrolled window in a jQuery Mobile popup dialog does not work and simply jumps to the top?

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="chkSelector" data-overlay-theme="a"  
        data-theme="a" data-dismissible="true">

        <div style="width:500px; height:300px; overflow-y:auto;">
            <label for="checkbox-1">021669835973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-2">021669835976</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-3">021669835983</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-4">021669836973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-4" id="checkbox-4" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-5">021669837973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-5" id="checkbox-5" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-6">021669855973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-6" id="checkbox-6" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-7">021669935973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-7" id="checkbox-7" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-8">021669835973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-8" id="checkbox-8" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-9">021669835976</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-9" id="checkbox-9" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-10">021669835983</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-10" id="checkbox-10" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-11">021669836973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-11" id="checkbox-11" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-12">021669837973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-12" id="checkbox-12" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-13">021669855973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-13" id="checkbox-13" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-14">021669935973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-14" id="checkbox-14" type="checkbox">                         
        </div> 

    </div>
```

Only the top ones not cut off below the window height can be selected. Whe the lower ones are scrolled into view and selected, the list just scrolls to the top without selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for the reason of that, i believe that simply `Popups` aren't intended and deeply tested for *a lot of interactive content*, but just for small hints or small navigation menues. If you need to present to the user *a lot of interactive content*, IMHO a page with the `Dialog` option is a better choice. Just my two cents.

If you are then asking for a workaround, here is it. Just initialize an [External Popup](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup-outside-multipage/) and use that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#chkSelector").enhanceWithin().popup();
});
```

```css
.ui-popup .ui-checkbox {
  margin-right: 0.5em !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="menu">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#chkSelector" class="ui-btn" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div data-role="popup" id="chkSelector" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" class="ui-content" data-dismissible="true">
        <div style="width:500px; height:300px; overflow-y:auto;">
            <label for="checkbox-1">021669835973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-2">021669835976</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-3">021669835983</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-4">021669836973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-4" id="checkbox-4" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-5">021669837973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-5" id="checkbox-5" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-6">021669855973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-6" id="checkbox-6" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-7">021669935973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-7" id="checkbox-7" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-8">021669835973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-8" id="checkbox-8" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-9">021669835976</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-9" id="checkbox-9" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-10">021669835983</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-10" id="checkbox-10" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-11">021669836973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-11" id="checkbox-11" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-12">021669837973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-12" id="checkbox-12" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-13">021669855973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-13" id="checkbox-13" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-14">021669935973</label> 
            <input name="checkbox-14" id="checkbox-14" type="checkbox">                         
        </div> 
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```